# Node ExpressJS: middleware URL route response vs route destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.originalUrl == '/api/test'){
        //does stuff
        res.send(result);
    }
    next();
})
```

vs

```
route.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
   //does stuff
   res.send(result)
}
```

I'm rather unfamiliar with the whole HTTP web application safety conduct so I need to ask, is there any vulnerability or downside if I use the first approach to resolve some of the route destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm rather unfamiliar with the whole HTTP web application safety conduct so I need to ask, is there any vulnerability or downside if I use the first approach to resolve some of the route destination?

There are two main differences between `router.use()` and `router.get()` and one is somewhat relevant here:

1. `router.use()` matches ANY http verb such as GET, POST, PUT, OPTION, PATCH, etc...  whereas `router.get()` only matches GET requests, `router.post()` only matches POST requests, etc..
2. `router.use()` uses a "loose" match algorithm where the requested route only has to start with the path designation on the route, not match it entirely.

For the first point, your middleware handler is doing `res.send(response)` for all http verbs that have a request path of `/api/test`.  That is probably not what you want and is not how you should write the code.  You should have your code respond only to the http verbs for that path that you actually intend to support and do something useful with.  Other verbs should probably respond with a 4xx status code (which would be the default in Express if you don't have a handler for them).

For the second point, your middleware handler is generic (no path set) and you are already checking for the entire path so that point is not relevant.

With one small addition, I'd say that your middleware approach is fine.  I'd add a check for the `req.method`:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.method === "GET" && req.originalUrl == '/api/test'){
        //does stuff
        res.send(result);
        // return so the rest of the route handler is not executed
        // and we don't call next()
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

---

All that said, you can also probably solve your problem in a bit more generic way.  For example, if you put a specific route definition in front of this middleware, then it will automatically be exempted from the middleware as it will get processed before the middleware gets to run.  Routes in Express are matched and run in the order they are declared.

```
router.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
   //does stuff
   res.send(result)
});

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    // do some middleware prep work on all requests that get here
    // ...
    next();
});

// other route definitions here that can use the results of the prior middleware
```

For example, this is very common if you have some routes that need authentication and others that do not.  You put the non-authenticated routes first, then place the authentication middleware, then define the routes that want to be behind the authentication check.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I needed. Your first point is a great addition and I will definitely be more aware of it. As for the 2nd points, not sure where I got the misconception that middleware are always performed first, but your reminder does fix my misconception. The original question asked was exactly because I was trying to do authentication related application and your answer helps a lot.

Comment: @Aii - Note one edit, I just added.  After you call `res.send()` in the middleware, you need to `return` so the code does not continue executing and call `next()`.  Glad this is what you needed.

Comment: may i also ask, is there ways to insert a middleware that would trigger at the end of every selected route?

Comment: @Aii - No that I know of, but there's probably some mechanism that logging uses to track when a response is sent that could be hacked into.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "exact" vulnerability, but many, many drawbacks. The major difference here is that the first piece of code is what we call "a global handler". It is executed on each and every request. The second piece is just a specific route.

When you make a request, express starts to evaluate the pipeline of things it needs to do in order to return a response. First it executes all global handlers (like the first example). Then it starts matching the route against a list of handlers, and if it finds it - it executes the function.

What you risk using the first approach is breaking the chain and not executing all global/local handlers properly. Some of those might do specific things (like preventing you from some type of attacks). Then, using the second approach, you define way more things than just a global handler: you define the endpoint, as well as the method (in your case it's a `GET` request).

When the matcher finds your route, it does break the chain automatically for you (in the simplest scenario).

Also note that in the first example, you'd have a single point with tons of `if-else` statements to figure out what you want to do with this request. It basically mitigates the need of express whatsoever...

---

Express is made in a way that it supports multiple "middlewares". If you want to do specific pieces based on some action, here's what you can do:

```js
router.get('/users',
  handler1(req, res, next) {
    if (req.something) {
      next(); // we skip the logic here, but we go to handler2
    } else {
      // do your magic
      res.send(response);
    }
  },
  handler2(req, res, next) {
    // you skipped the action from handler1
    res.send(anotherResponse); // you MUST send a response in one handler
  }
```

Comment: You can always use multiple middleware handlers, that's what express is for! :) I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I'm currently trying to achieve is to have specific action to be exempted from the handler. Since there is no way to place one single destination route before the handler, I have resorted to use the first approach. As below:

`router.use((req, res, next) => {`
`//typical handler action`
`})`

`router.use((req, res, next) => {`
`//exception`
`if(url){`
`res.send();`
`}`

`//typical handler action`
`next();`
`})`

Comment: You could easily do both, but I'd strongly advise you from using your method. What you could have `router.use` (not global, but per router), and also add routes for testing **separately** like `if (testing) { app.use('/tests', testRouter) }`